# How to retrieve foreign key constraints data

Tags: oracle, query, foreign-key

I'm looking for a query allowing to retrieve foreign key infos (each line: referrencing table & field, referrenced table & field) of an entire schema.

I've found this, but does not gives all the info I need: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389228/sql-for-oracle-to-check-if-a-constraint-exists

I'm currently working on it and may end up with a solution in the next minutes/hours. But if someone has already a full working solution, I'll be glad to know it :)

Comment: For SQL Developer, you can find this info in an ERD format in the 'Model' tab on a table (as referenced [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31926359/919057). Not useful for a script, but if you just need the info and land here like I did, it may be helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some "reverse-engineering" on the queries made by the [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/) tool when opening the **design table** window for a table (queries retrieving info about foreign keys show up in the **history** window), here is a solution:

```
SELECT
    CONS.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    CONS.TABLE_NAME,
    COLS.COLUMN_NAME,
    CONS.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    CONS_R.TABLE_NAME R_TABLE_NAME,
    COLS_R.COLUMN_NAME R_COLUMN_NAME

FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS CONS
    LEFT JOIN USER_CONS_COLUMNS COLS ON COLS.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CONS.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    LEFT JOIN USER_CONSTRAINTS CONS_R ON CONS_R.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CONS.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
    LEFT JOIN USER_CONS_COLUMNS COLS_R ON COLS_R.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CONS.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME

-- returns only foreign key constraints
WHERE CONS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R'

ORDER BY CONS.TABLE_NAME, COLS.COLUMN_NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Developer ships with a report that does just this.

It does it for the login schema only, but it's a quick fix to make it go get every single FK in the database - although you might want to omit schemas like 'APEX...' and 'SYS.'

It also omits things like, tables in the recycle bin.

The original report is in the Reports panel, in the data dictionary reports.

Here's the amended query to get ALL the FKs.

```
    SELECT
    c.owner "Owner",
    c.table_name "Table_Name",
    c.constraint_name "Constraint_Name",
    c.delete_rule "Delete_Rule",
    d.columns,
    c.r_owner "Owner of Related Table",
    (
        SELECT
            r.table_name
        FROM
            sys.all_constraints r
        WHERE
            c.r_owner = r.owner
        AND
            c.r_constraint_name = r.constraint_name
    ) "Related Table",
    c.r_constraint_name "Related Constraint"
FROM
    sys.all_constraints c,
    (
        SELECT
            a.owner,
            a.table_name,
            a.constraint_name,
            MAX(
                DECODE(position,1,substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            )
             ||  MAX(
                DECODE(position,2,','
                 ||  substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            )
             ||  MAX(
                DECODE(position,3,','
                 ||  substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            )
             ||  MAX(
                DECODE(position,4,','
                 ||  substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            )
             ||  MAX(
                DECODE(position,5,','
                 ||  substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            )
             ||  MAX(
                DECODE(position,6,','
                 ||  substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            )
             ||  MAX(
                DECODE(position,7,','
                 ||  substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            )
             ||  MAX(
                DECODE(position,8,','
                 ||  substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            )
             ||  MAX(
                DECODE(position,9,','
                 ||  substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            )
             ||  MAX(
                DECODE(position,10,','
                 ||  substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            )
             ||  MAX(
                DECODE(position,11,','
                 ||  substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            )
             ||  MAX(
                DECODE(position,12,','
                 ||  substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            )
             ||  MAX(
                DECODE(position,13,','
                 ||  substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            )
             ||  MAX(
                DECODE(position,14,','
                 ||  substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            )
             ||  MAX(
                DECODE(position,15,','
                 ||  substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            )
             ||  MAX(
                DECODE(position,16,','
                 ||  substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)
            ) columns
        FROM
            sys.all_constraints a,
            sys.all_cons_columns b
        WHERE
            a.constraint_name = b.constraint_name
        AND
            a.owner = b.owner
        AND
            a.constraint_type = 'R'
        AND
            substr(a.table_name,1,4) != 'BIN$'
        AND
            substr(a.table_name,1,3) != 'DR$'
        AND (
                :table_name IS NULL
            OR
                instr(upper(a.table_name),upper(:table_name) ) > 0
        ) GROUP BY
            a.owner,
            a.table_name,
            a.constraint_name
    ) d
WHERE
    c.owner = d.owner
AND
    c.table_name = d.table_name
AND
    c.constraint_name = d.constraint_name
ORDER BY
    c.owner,
    c.table_name,
    c.constraint_name
```

And here's what that report looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A little bit complicated code which also dump comments on cols (based on Frosty code):

```
SELECT
    dt.table_name, dt.column_name, dt.data_type, dt.data_length,
    constr.r_tbl r_table, constr.r_col r_column,
    comm.comments
  FROM user_col_comments comm, user_tab_columns dt
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
      cons.table_name tbl,
      cols.column_name col,
      cons_r.table_name r_tbl,
      cols_r.column_name r_col
    FROM user_constraints cons
      LEFT JOIN user_cons_columns cols ON cols.constraint_name = cons.constraint_name
      LEFT JOIN user_constraints cons_r ON cons_r.constraint_name = cons.r_constraint_name
      LEFT JOIN user_cons_columns cols_r ON cols_r.constraint_name = cons.r_constraint_name
    WHERE cons.constraint_type = 'R'
    ) constr ON constr.tbl = dt.table_name AND constr.col = dt.column_name
  WHERE dt.table_name = comm.table_name
    AND dt.column_name = comm.column_name
  ORDER BY dt.table_name, dt.column_name
  ;
```

To make output more readable I use `break on TABLE_NAME;` in `sqlplus` (look to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998296/print-only-first-unique-value-for-column-that-order-by-in-oracle-sqlplus/ ).

**UPDATE** Simpler query that collects list of tables that have FK reference to given table (useful if you like to clean up constraints after table renames):

```
select * from SYS.USER_CONSTRAINTS cons
  join SYS.USER_CONSTRAINTS rcons on rcons.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cons.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
  where cons.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' and rcons.TABLE_NAME 'TBL_NAME';

select * from SYS.USER_CONSTRAINTS cons
  join SYS.USER_CONSTRAINTS rcons on rcons.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cons.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
  where cons.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' and rcons.TABLE_NAME like '%/_OLD' escape '/';
```

Answer (score 2):

Found out that most of these scripts have issues when foreign key constraint references a table with more than one column reference.

Here is the one I use:

```
    SELECT c.constraint_name,
           l.table_name,
           l.column_name,
           r.table_name,
           r.column_name
      FROM user_constraints c,
           user_cons_columns l,
           user_cons_columns r
     WHERE l.table_name = c.table_name
    -- AND c.table_name = :tname
       AND c.r_constraint_name = r.constraint_name
       AND c.constraint_name = l.constraint_name
       AND l.position = r.position
```